# Question about beta - trading

Tags: trading, stock-analysis, beta

I've been a bit stuck with this question:
"If a portfolio P had a predicted beta=1.05 wrt to an index, and that index later underperformed Treasury Bills by 5%, what would be the expected return of the portfolio P?".

I think the answer is just -0.0525 (essentialy 1.05*(-0.05)), but I'd like to check.

Comment: Sorry, had to get rid of the last comment.  Yeah the portfolio would be expected to under-perform by 5.25%. T-Bills don't have a 0% return however so find the T-Bill return and then take the T-Bill return (.45%) and take 5.25% off of it. (.0045 - (.0045*.0525)) = .0043  or (1-.0525)(.0045) = .0043  Had a brain fart on the first try.

Comment: @Ross, can you put that in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Ross last seen Jan ‘17